# Date formatting in VisualForce

Tags: apex, visualforce, date

I'm currently doing this to get the formatting in the image below. Could somebody please explain to me how I can also display the day of the week here?

(Monday, Tuesday Wednesday) or (Mon, Tues, Wed)

```
<apex:outputText id="outputDates" value="{0,date,MMM'.'dd', 'yyyy}">
     <apex:param value="{!conAcc.Next_Arrival__r.Arrival_Date__c}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "EEE" to show the abbreviated version, or "EEEE" to show the long version. This follows the same rules as [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Example:

```
<apex:outputText id="outputDates" value="{0,date,EEE', 'MMM'.'dd', 'yyyy}">
     <apex:param value="{!conAcc.Next_Arrival__r.Arrival_Date__c}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```